# How to launch chrome from a Custom Port using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Exception** in thread `"main"`

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
java.net.ConnectException: 
Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:44248
```

I am frequently getting this error. The script runs halfway and then the exception occurs. Is there a way to avoid this.

Also, can we assign a **particular port explicitly to web-driver execution**, if yes, how can we do it

**WebDriverConfig function**

```
public static WebDriver DriverConfigDetails() {
 File src = new File("src");
 File driverloc = new File(src, "chromedriver.exe");
 System.out.println("\nDriver Path: " + driverloc.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverloc.getAbsolutePath());
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 return driver;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: public static WebDriver DriverConfigDetails() {

  File src = new File("src");
  File driverloc = new File(src, "chromedriver.exe");

  System.out.println("\nDriver Path: " + driverloc.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverloc.getAbsolutePath());
 
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  return driver;

 }

Comment: Please provide your Main Class code where you are using this function

Comment: is there any way to specify the localhost port for selenium explicitly

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you can assign a particular port explicitly to your web-driver execution.**

If you know the port you want to connect to, then you can directly connect to it using selenium with below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
chromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:<customPort>");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Also, there is one another option to launch chrome browser at some custom port with below code:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=<customPort> --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\AutomationProfile"
```

and then use that port for your execution with selenium.

Note: Just make sure that the custom port you are trying to use for your execution is not being used by any other application.

[Reference](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/42014/37791)

Comment: Hi, this doesn't start webdriver on the specific port, this just allows connecting to a chrome instance remotely(or from script) through the specified port, if the chrome is opened in the debugging mode through that port.

Comment: @PDHide Yes, 2nd part of the code does the same as you said. But the first part of code can open the chrome at the custom part and one can do their execution on that port.

Comment: first part doesn't work if chrome is not already opened with the second part. It throws error , saying cannot connect at 127.0.0.1:port

Comment: @PDHide It's working well with me.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to assign a particular port explicitly to web-driver execution

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your driver path");
chromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "yourcustomport");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Custom port should be provided along with your hostname

yourcustomport: `127.0.0.1:2100`

**note:** your chrome browser should be running in this port

Answer (score 1):

**Runnin chromedriver on a specific port:**

**You should use ChromeDriverService for starting chrome in a different port:**

```
       import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.WebDriver;
       import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
       import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
       import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;        


        WebDriver browser = null;

        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\chromedriver.exe"))
        .usingPort(4444) 
        .build();

        service.start(); 

        browser = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), new ChromeOptions());
```

Once your tests are done, make sure to close the browser and the service:

```
browser.quit()
service.stop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Running chrome on a specific debug port:**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=1557");
    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
    options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1557");
    browser=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**output:**

[image]